# Entity reference autocomplete field node

Tags: entities, services

I am using Services module to create nodes via an api and am having problems using entity reference autocomplete to populate the field.

The ER field is linked to a taxonomy and uses a multi field setting so that more than one value can be set. I have tried multiple different options including a var_dump of the node entity upon insert and can see its not being set.

The following are the 6 ways I tried to set the field. Do you have any idea? I am using the latest Services module and the ER module.

```
{"und": ["112326"]}

{"und": [{"target_id":"112326"}]}

{"und": [{"target_id":"A S (112326)"}]}

{"und": ["A S (112326)"]}

{"und": [{"tid":"A S (112326)"}]}

{"und": [{"tid":112326}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to handle multi value fields you'll need this patch: https://www.drupal.org/node/2224803#comment-11477609

Second, depending on what Widget you have selected for your Entity Reference field, this does/can change what Services expects to be POST/PUT up to the server.

I personally always set the Widget as an Autocomplete, and then this JSON format is the correct one to use:

```
var node = {
  type: 'article',
  title: 'Hello world',
  language: 'und',
  field_foo: {
    und: [
      { target_id: '... (123)' }
    ]
  }
};
```

You can literally put anything you want in the position of the `...`, the only thing that matters is the Entity ID is wrapped in the parenthesis.